# Live checker csv by python

Tags: python, csv, reader

How to check `csv` data by python live (I mean every 0.1 second)?
When I am using this code:

```
while True:
    with open('file.csv') as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
        for row in csvReader:
            url.append(row[1])
            if url[1] == "WAIT":
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            else:
                break
```

When I change data manually in csv I get this error:  
process cannot get access to file because being used another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to note, When you access the CSV file, your code will not be able to load it. Once you close the file, it will be loaded again.

To make your code wait for you to close the file you should use the `try/except` method with the exception ending with `continue`.

```
while True:
    try:
        with open('file.csv') as csvDataFile:
            csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
            for row in csvReader:
                url.append(row[1])
                if url[1] == "WAIT":
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                else:
                    break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The try/except should be within the `while True`  loop. Fixed the code in the answer

Comment: Bro I got it :D every loop url[1] always be same so I must clear list. Ty so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
while True:
    with open("file.csv","r") as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)

    #Your Code#

    time.sleep(0.1)
```